# Can I apply to become a Dutch Citizen under the Option Procedure?

Tags: citizenship, netherlands

My mother was born in 1930. She came to London, UK in 1954. In 1956 she married my father. I believe - though I cannot find the papers - that under the law at this time, after 5 years she would automatically become a British citizen. My parents divorced around 1974. I was born in 1964. My mother is now deceased. I have found a Dutch passport for my mother from between 1999 and 2004 (she died in 2013). I can find no other records of nationality or dual nationality for my mother from the time I was born. I wish to apply for Dutch citizenship. Does anyone know if or if there is a chance that I may be eligible?

Comment: It seems likely to me, but since my Dutch parent is my father I'm less familiar with the rules concerning mothers and the option procedure. If they issued her a passport in 1999 then it's unlikely that they would find that she'd lost her Dutch nationality before 1964.  If I remember correctly that should make you eligible for the option procedure.